# Flatmap fails to cast to right one

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I am trying to transform an Observable in my login function but I keep getting this error. This my code and error I am getting on flatMap

```
fun login(phoneNumber: String, password: String, deviceId: String) {
        // remove previous subscriptions
        disposables.clear()

        // function to save userInfo and access token
        val saveResponse = { response: LoginResponse ->
            val user = response?.user
            val token = response?.token
//            userManager.updateToken(champion, token, deviceId)
        }

        // on success callback
        val onSuccess = { isSuccess: Boolean ->
            progressBarVisibility.postValue(false)
            loginSuccess.postValue(isSuccess)
            if (!isSuccess) errorMessage.postValue("An error occurred please try again.")
        }

        // on failure callback
        val onError = { throwable: Throwable ->
            val message = when (throwable) {
                is HttpException -> when (throwable.code()) {
                    400 -> "Enter valid Phone Number or Password"
                    422 -> "Incorrect Phone Number or Password"
                    else -> throwable.toErrorMessage()
                }

                else -> "An Error Occurred."
            }

            // show error message
            errorMessage.postValue(message)
            progressBarVisibility.postValue(false)
        }

        val disposable = accountUseCase.login(LoginRequest(phoneNumber, password)).observeOnUI()
                .doOnSubscribe { progressBarVisibility.postValue(true) }
                .flatMap {
                    val resp = it.data
                    when (resp) {
                        null -> Single.just(false)
                        else -> saveResponse(it)
                    }
                }
                .subscribe(onSuccess, onError)

        // add subscription to disposables
        disposables.add(disposable)
    }
```

error

```
Type mismatch. Required: ((BaseResponse<LoginResponse>!) → SingleSource<out (???..???)>!)! Found: (BaseResponse<LoginResponse>!) → Any!
```

Comment: the one branch of your `when` is returning a single, what does `saveResponse` return ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the implicit return of your `flatMap`:

```
when (resp) {
    null -> Single.just(false)
    else -> saveResponse(it)
}
```

In the `null` branch, the return type is `Single<Boolean>`.

In the `else` branch, you return the result of `saveResponse`. But the return type of `saveResponse` is `Unit`, because it doesn't return anything.

Kotlin therefore infers the return type of your `flatMap` to be either `Single<Boolean>` or `Unit`, and the only common supertype of these is `Any`.

This is why you get the error message: `Found: (BaseResponse<LoginResponse>!) → Any!`

You need to have `saveResponse` return something, probably also a `Single<Boolean>`, depending on your usecase.